# how do I make webpack-dev-server respect rbenv configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, rvm, webpack-dev-server, rbenv

I've got an existing rails app using `webpacker` and I just attempted to migrate from `rvm` to `rbenv`. Everything appeared to be working in my automated tests, but when I try to fire up `bin/webpack-dev-server`, it seems to want to use the System ruby rather than the one specified by my `Gemfile` (and my `.ruby-version`). It tells me:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from ./webpack-dev-server:12:in '<main>'`
```

As near as I can tell, this is happening because of the following line at the top of the `webpack-dev-server` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

but I do not know how to make it work properly with rbenv. When I run `rails webpacker:check_binstubs`, it does not show me any errors, but clearly there is a problem. Did I miss a step in removing `rvm`? Please help.

Comment: Maybe try  a `gem install bundler`  ?

Comment: I could do that, and `sudo` it to install it to the system, but that breaks the whole point of using `rbenv`.